# TSQL Recursive query with the initial data inside

Tags: sql, recursive-query

I am trying to do a recursive query (t-sql).
I've managed to do that, however I am not sure how to add initial data to all rows (id)

So for example, I want to get all deputies of A1 and all deputies of their deputies.
However I would like to tag all row that they 'belong to' A1 hierarchy.

My query is like this as below:

```
WITH finaltable 
AS
(
select b.*
from 
mytable b
where b.id = 'A1'

UNION ALL

select rec.*
from 
mytable rec
INNER JOIN finaltable f
ON f.deputy_id= rec.id
)
SELECT *
FROM finaltable
```

What I am getting is this:

| id | deputy_id |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 |
| A1 | B2 |
| B1 | null |
| B2 | C1 |
| C1 | null |

What I would like to have it like that:

| id | deputy_id | top_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | A1 |
| A1 | B2 | A1 |
| B1 | null | A1 |
| B2 | C1 | A1 |
| C1 | null | A1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep any starting data in extra columns

```
WITH finaltable 
AS
(
    select b.*, b.id top_id
    from mytable b
    where b.id = 'A1'

    UNION ALL

    select rec.*, f.top_id
    from mytable rec
    INNER JOIN finaltable f
    ON f.deputy_id= rec.id
)
SELECT *
FROM finaltable
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying with 'f.id top_id' and it gave me only parent level.